# jqGrid - PHP/mySQL (Missed something?)

Tags: php, mysql, jqgrid

PHP Code:

```
$Re = $ZD -> query($PullSearchInfoSQL);
$Rn = $ZD -> found_rows;
if($Rn > 0 && $limit > 0){$Rn = ceil($Rn/$limit);}else{$Rn = 0;}
if($page > $Rn) $page = $Rn;
$start = $limit * $page - $limit;
$Re = $ZD -> query($PullSearchInfoSQL.' LIMIT '.$start.','.$limit);
while($Ro = $ZD -> fetch_assoc($Re)){
    $PullSearchInfoData[] = array('X' => Coords($Ro['SCFieldID']),'P' => $Ro['SCPlayer'],'C' => $Ro['SCCastle'],'F' => $Ro['SCFlag'],'A' => $Ro['SCAlliance'],'S' => PlayerStatus($Ro['SCStatus']),'D' => $Ro['SCSnapA']);
}
$PullSearchInfoData = array('page' => $page,'num' => $Rn,'cell' => $PullSearchInfoData);
echo json_encode($PullSearchInfoData);
```

jqGrid:

```
$('#PlayerInformation').jqGrid({
                    url: DateFile+'Data.php?Load=PullSearchInfo&MOpt='+MOpt+'&Data='+$('#SearchThis').val()+'&Parm='+$('#SearchOption').val().split('^')[0]+'&Opts='+$('#SearchOption').val().split('^')[1],
                    datatype:'json',
                    colModel:[
                        {label:'X , Y',name:'X',width:44,align:'left',sortable:false},
                        {label:'Player',name:'P',width:68,align:'left',sortable:false},
                        {label:'Castle',name:'C',width:68,align:'left',sortable:false},
                        {label:'Flag',name:'F',width:28,align:'left',sortable:false},
                        {label:'Alliance',name:'A',width:68,align:'left',sortable:false},
                        {label:'S',name:'S',width:10,align:'center',sortable:false},
                        {label:'Date',name:'D',width:77,align:'center',sortable:false}
                    ],
                    rowNum:1000, altRows:true, height:507, pager:'#PlayerInfoPager',
                    loadComplete: function(){
                            $('#AllPlaTitle').empty().html('History for [ '+$('#SearchThis').val()+ ' ] '+$(this).jqGrid('getGridParam','reccount')+' Listed');
                            $('#PlayerInformation').highlight($('#SearchThis').val(),true);
                            $('#SearchGo,#SearchHist').show();
                            $('#SearchOption,#SearchThis').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                });
```

Database Query Result:

```
{"page":"1","num":1,"cell":[{"X":"104,135","P":"Gaia of Vansterdam","C":"Hamster","F":"XXX","A":null,"S":"P","D":"01\/07\/15 13:08"},{"X":"102,115","P":"Gaia of Vansterdam","C":"Vansterdam","F":"XXX","A":null,"S":"P","D":"01\/07\/15 13:08"},{"X":"301,3","P":"VonVander","C":"VV1","F":"Von","A":"g144","S":"P","D":"01\/07\/15 13:08"}]}
```

Before adding page/num to the JSON, everything was working fine.  Until I added page/num, followed instruction on the jqGRID site, I can't for the life outta me figure out why the data is not displaying on the grid.  Was my JSON output wrong?  Was my PHP layout incorrect?

Thanks for your help in advance!
Sean

Comment: You're setting the `url:` parameter when the grid is first loaded, so you're getting things like `$('#SearchThis').val()` before the user has filled in the field, not after they modify it.

Comment: How do you set the variables `$limit` and `$page`?

Comment: ohh, you mean callback?

Answer (score 0):

I've found my flaw and based on what Barmar suggested, see above post, all is correct, only fixed below:

Fixed mySQL:

```
    $count = $ZD -> found_rows;
    if($count > 0 && $limit > 0){$total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);}else{$total_pages = 0;}
    if($page > $total_pages) $page = $total_pages;
    $start = $limit * $page - $limit;
    if($start < 0) $start = 0;
```

and Array method:

```
$PullSearchInfoData = array('total' => (int)$total_pages,'page' => (int)$page,'records' => (int)$count,'rows' => $PullSearchInfoData);
```

Got the result I was looking for and pulls all the data properly into the jqGRID :)
Thanks for helping Barmar!
Sean